# Explanation as to why a script is a better method for updating the Mac OS X locate database

Tags: macos, locate

I use `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` on Mac OS X when I am too impatient to wait for it's scheduled script to kick in and run, which I believe is only once a month.

Mac OS X doesn't use cron/other schedulers, but instead ( *at least pre Yosemite* ), launchd is used, which is like `cron` only more granular w/ more options, at the expense of a bit of over verbosity in my humble opinion.

Researching, I [found this website](https://coderwall.com/p/eexczq/update-osx-s-locate-database-welcome-back-updatedb) which states that the below code is:

> ...In a moment of glorious chance, I happened to come across this handy little bash script and I nearly palmed my face clean off because I hadn't thought of it.

```
pushd . > /dev/null
cd /usr/libexec
echo "Updating locate database..."
sudo ./locate.updatedb
echo "Updating complete!"
popd > /dev/null
```

Can someone walk me though this, I have read the man page on each, but don't see the advantage.  If you /usr/libexec before running ./locate.updatedb I fail to see why you would need the above script.  It seems like a bit of overheard to manage another file, in your PATH, when you can just `cd` into the executable and go from there.

Comment: I believe the gist of the blog post is that the author is used to the command `updatedb` and writing a script lets him use that command specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I couldn't figure out the advabtage. So this is just a convenience script for his workflow.  Any method that fires off the update script will suffice.

His script just makes sure you are in the correct `cwd`

Thank you for the input.